# Layerslider and usijng hyper link to a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using layerslider plugin to show rotating sliders on my homepage and those sliders are working as hyperlinks, one of the hyperlinks should go to a pop up menu, but it seems class="ls-link" is the only class I can use, and the Jquery pop has it is own class="open-popup-link", how can make the layerslider show that pop up when the user clicks on the slider?

How I can do that?

Layerslider code + standard slider hyperlink

```
<div class="ls-slide" data-ls="slidedelay:8000 ; transition2d:5;timeshift:0;">

<img src="/img/Slide1.png" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background"/>
<a href="/users/login" class="ls-link" </a>

</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Regular html Hyperlink for pop up:

```
<a href="/users/register" id="register-link" class="open-popup-link" >Login</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add class in it like `class="ls-link open-popup-link"`.

```
<a href="/users/login" class="ls-link open-popup-link">Click</a>
```